# Is there a utility for detecting temporary system freezes?

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, system-monitoring

Is there a (unix) utility which is able to **detect temporary system freezes** by observation?

E.g. I could imagine an utility which continuously fetches the system time, sleeps for a specific amount of time and checks that elapsed system time matches more or less the last remembered system time + sleep_interval + margin and if not, reports this incident.

Before writing something on my own, is there already something similar available (my google  search has been negative so far).

Comment: Why do you expect your system to freeze?

Comment: A system freeze is a possible theory of a specific application failure I am investigating. I'd like to validate this theory. I also noticed yesterday that my bash locked up for a few seconds which increases my confidence. On the other hand system freezes can happen in certain scenarios, e.g. if you think of hardware (interrupt) issues, kernel bugs or driver failures.

Comment: Yeah, but a system reeze - while it DOES happen I have never seen one with those symptoms. System freezes are mostly driver / hardware and do not recover, which is why watchdog hardware exits that works with a driver and triggers a reset when the driver is not pinging the hardware. NEVER seen a "temporary" system freeze. In like 30 years.

Comment: @TomTom Linux kernel bug fixes in git logs have some examples of freezes that do recover. Example: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-5.19.y&id=81ea010667417ef3f218dfd99b69769fe66c2b67 -> https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460 -> https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/attachment.cgi?id=607  . You'll get the kernel detect itself a temporary cpu lockup (actually the fix isn't perfect and has a pending fix too).